# Realm very slow for adding/updating records

Tags: react-native, realm

I have this react native application which imports the phone contacts to database. I have about 100 contacts in my phone and it's taking ages...like 1 import per second which is. I'm sure, a mistake I'm doing somewhere even though the code is simple.

```
    realm.write(() => {
        for (let i = 0, len = contacts.length; i < len; i++) {
            Contact.saveOrUpdate(contacts[i].name, contacts[i].recordID, contacts[i].phoneNumbers);
        }
    });
```

`saveOrUpdate` method:

```
class Contact {
    static saveOrUpdate(name, recordId, phones) {
        const save = () => {
            let c;

            try {
                // try an update first
                c = realm.create('Contact', {
                    name: name.toString(),
                    recordID: recordId.toString()
                }, true);
            } catch (e) {
                // if that fails, create a new contact
                console.log("Created " + recordId);
                c = realm.create('Contact', {
                    name: name.toString(),
                    recordID: recordId.toString()
                });
            }

            c.phones = [];

            for (let i = 0, len = phones.length; i < len; i++) {
                c.phones.push({
                    number: phones[i].toString()
                });
            }

            // now run an update with the phone numbers
            return realm.create('Contact', c, true);
        };

        return save();
    }
}
```

My realm schema:

```
const PhoneNumberSchema = {
    name: 'PhoneNumber',
    properties: {
        number: 'string'
    }
};

const ContactSchema = {
    name: 'Contact',
    primaryKey: 'recordID',
    properties: {
        recordID: 'string',
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            indexed: true
        },
        phones: {
            type: 'list',
            objectType: 'PhoneNumber'
        }
    }
};
```

Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong here that it takes so long for 100 contacts to be stored?

Comment: Well checking the existence of an item based on whether you get an exception certainly seems like something that has overhead.

Comment: Are you running your app in release mode? Doing Realm operations can be really slow in debug mode.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Realm on debug mode is painfully slow but runs ok in production.

Comment: The slowness you experience in Debug is most likely due to Remote JS Debugging. If you've got the Chrome debugger attached to your app then your JavaScript code runs in Chrome but your realm files live on the device and accessing them from Chrome will be slow.

Comment: facing same! 2000 records took too long to save